# Gnuplot how to make x-axis 1,3,5 ... instead of 1,2,3,4,

Tags: gnuplot

I have a text file with a single column of data generated from a C program that I am plotting via gnuplot. Without generating an additional column for the index from the C program, i.e without changing the data from, say:

"stat".txt"

```
23423
43543
45562
32423
```

to

```
1 23423
3 43543
5 45562
7 32423
```

can I make gnuplot change the x axis numbering from 1,2,3,4,... to 1,3,5,7...

When I `plot "stat.txt"` the corresponding x value to each row entry is by default 1,2,3,4...

Presently, I did add an additional column for the index and used the command `plot "stat.txt" using 1:2` but I am curious to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column 0 in gnuplot is the record number.

```
plot "stat.txt" using (2*$0-1):1
```

will give you 1,3,5 for the x values on the plot.